# How to change the box border of JavaFX CheckBox?

Tags: javafx, checkbox, jfoenix

How can i change the box border color and radius of JFXCheckBox ? (i am using the JFoenix library)

Is there any cool JavaFX libraries for CheckBox except JFoenix ?

[image: Details in picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change border color of JFXCheckBox use `-jfx-unchecked-color` css property

```
checkBox.setStyle("-jfx-unchecked-color: red");
```

Comment: How can i change the size and the radius of the box ?